# When does display the prompt that is "Would you like to save this password in your iCloud Keychain"?

Tags: swift, keychain

When does display the prompt that is "Would you like to save this password in your iCloud Keychain"??

I'm implementing the keychain logic to save passwords.
But, It is not displayed this prompt when creating a Keychain for Application Password.
Is it need for me to use another kSecClass Item?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlhSw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a documentation for keychain password saving [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1617986-secaddsharedwebcredential)

```
func SecAddSharedWebCredential(_ fqdn: CFString, 
                             _ account: CFString, 
                             _ password: CFString?, 
                             _ completionHandler: @escaping (CFError?) -> Void)
```

- fqdn: domain name of the website requiring the password.
- account: The account name associated with this password.
- password: The password to be stored. Pass NULL to remove a shared password if it exists.
- completionHandler: A block invoked when the function has completed.

Comment: Thank you very much !!
Does it only display this prompt when uses Shared Web Credentials and kSecClassInternetPassword?
Can I display this prompt when use kSecClassGenericPassword?